# Check function inside an inframe function

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, click

I want to execute a function to update inside an `iframe` click script

```
<script>
    var monitor = setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.activeElement;
        if (elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME') {
            message.innerHTML = 'Clicked'
            // here ajax execute, but doesn't work, it loads the whole script without clicking it.
            clearInterval(monitor);
        }
    }, 100);
</script>

<div id="framerefresh">
    <iframe rel="nofollow" src="adsense.htm" id="iframe" name="frame1" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "250px" width = "300px"></iframe>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

I really, really need some help with this. I want to run an update query when a click occurs inside the iframe.

Comment: Is it the click event of Iframe that has problem?

Comment: it`s the click event, it works like text, but when i put ajax in there, it posts it auto without the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#iframe').on('click', function(event) { 
              // Your ajax call
          });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: i did, when i click it no response, tested with a simple alert.

Comment: how i do that ? xD

Comment: Run your application and press F12 and check the console tab in it.